# Attempting to invoke PowerShell function with parameters

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm attempting to execute a function in a PowerShell script by calling said script through C#.  The function has two parameters.  However, I'm getting an error that the function isn't a recognized cmdlet, function, etc.  Based on my code, could someone assist me with what I'm doing wrong?

```
string powerShellScript = @"D:\TestTransform\transform.ps1";
IDictionary powerShellParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
powerShellParameters.Add("configFile", file);
powerShellParameters.Add("transformFile", transformFile);

Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
runspace.Open();

using (PowerShell powerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
{
    powerShellInstance.Runspace = runspace;
    powerShellInstance.AddScript(powerShellScript);
    powerShellInstance.Invoke();

    powerShellInstance.AddCommand("XmlDocTransform");
    powerShellInstance.AddParameters(powerShellParameters);

    Collection<PSObject> psOutput = powerShellInstance.Invoke(); //breaks here
}
```

My Powershell script:

```
function XmlDocTransform($xml, $xdt)
{
    if (!$xml -or !(Test-Path -path $xml -PathType Leaf)) {
        throw "File not found. $xml";
    }
    if (!$xdt -or !(Test-Path -path $xdt -PathType Leaf)) {
        throw "File not found. $xdt";
    }

    $scriptPath = $PSScriptRoot + "\"
    Add-Type -LiteralPath "$scriptPath\Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform.dll"

    $xmldoc = New-Object Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform.XmlTransformableDocument;
    $xmldoc.PreserveWhitespace = $true
    $xmldoc.Load($xml);

    $transf = New-Object Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform.XmlTransformation($xdt);
    if ($transf.Apply($xmldoc) -eq $false)
    {
        throw "Transformation failed."
    }
    $xmldoc.Save($xml);
}
```

Comment: .... var process = new Process(); .... process.Start(); why don't you use this approach?

Comment: How can I create a runspace to run multiple commands?

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work.  I've updated my code and included the PowerShell script.

Comment: You are not executing `D:\TestTransform\transform.ps1` in current scope, thus `XmlDocTransform` will be gone as soon as script finish. You are not cleaning commands after first `Invoke`, thus second `Invoke` effectively invoke `. {D:\TestTransform\transform.ps1} | XmlDocTransform …`. The names of parameters in `powerShellParameters` does not match names declared in `XmlDocTransform` function.

Answer (score 0):

Your function following some community best-practices:

```
function ConvertTo-XmlDoc {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType('System.Void')]
    param(
        [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory)]
        [ValidateScript({
            if (-not (Test-Path -Path $PSItem -PathType Leaf)) {
                throw "File not found: $PSItem"
            }
            return $true
        })]
        [string] $Xml,

        [Parameter(Position = 1, Mandatory)]
        [ValidateScript({
            if (-not (Test-Path -Path $PSItem -PathType Leaf)) {
                throw "File not found: $PSItem"
            }
            return $true
        })]
        [string] $Xdt
    )

    Add-Type -LiteralPath "$PSScriptRoot\Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform.dll"

    $xmldoc = [Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform.XmlTransformableDocument]::new()
    $xmldoc.PreserveWhitespace = $true
    $xmldoc.Load($Xml)

    $transform = [Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform.XmlTransformation]::new($Xdt)
    if (-not $transform.Apply($xmldoc)) {
        throw 'Transformation failed.'
    }
    $xmldoc.Save($Xml)
}
```

Followed by code that should work:

```
using (var ps = PowerShell.Create())
{
    ps.AddScript($@". 'D:\TestTransform\transform.ps1'; ConvertTo-XmlDoc -Xml {file} -Xdt {transformFile}");

    ps.Invoke();
}
```

Comment: None overload of `Create` accept string as its argument: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell.create?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0

Comment: @PetSerAl [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell.addscript?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0) is a bit misleading then.  There are multiple examples where the starting `Create` call is a command.  I've updated my answer following the words of the documentation rather than the examples now

Comment: `AddCommand` expect command name only, not script. You should pass just file name in first argument and `false` to second argument to invoke command in current scope. Also `params` is keyword in C#. You should use it like `@params`, if you want to use it as identifier.

Comment: @PetSerAl thanks for the feedback. I've updated my answer.